# Slider content with media query

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I am trying to create slider responsive. Roundabout slider will be used, actually roundabout is responsive but it is not working for me, so I decided to create custom media queries. The problem is `.rd-slider` is not showing in middle of the screen when screen size is less than 1199px in width. How do I place `.rd-slider` class middle on the screen? Here's my CSS

```
    #warper {
    border: 0 none;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
    width: auto;
}
.roundabout-holder {
    height: 30em;
    list-style: none outside none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
}
.roundabout-moveable-item {
    background-color: #CCCCCC;
    border: 1px solid #999999;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 300px;
    width: 450px;
}
.roundabout-in-focus {
    cursor: auto;
}
.rd-slider {
    width: auto;
}
.rslide {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 400px;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1199px) {
.warper {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #0000FF;
    border: 0 none;
    height: auto;
    padding: 0;
}
}
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1199px) {
.rd-slider {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FF0000;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 50px;
    width: auto;
}
}
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1199px) {
.rslide {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 300px;
}
}
```

And HTML

```
        <div id="warper">
        <div class="rd-slider">
            <ul class="rslide">
                <li><a href="#"><img src="#"></a></li>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: in your first media query `.warper` refers to a class where you have use an id in your html.

Comment: You only need to declare the media query once, but place the 3 classes inside the outer `{}`. Please supply a fiddle there is not enough information to see the problem you are having.

Comment: Oh God, these are the most ridiculous mistakes I am making very often. Hey how do ya handle this kind of things?

Comment: have a look at using css lint or using http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/#validate_by_input to validate your css. This will help catch some of your errors and teach you what to look out for.